# WiX: How to reference count shared DLLs when copied to another company's bin folder?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have two versions of my product which need to put some shared DLLs into another company's bin folder.  I was able to accomplish this by using the CopyFile Element, but I can't get the reference counting mechanism to work. The problem I am having is that when both version are installed (a supported scenario), and then one version gets uninstalled, these shared DLLs are removed which causes problems in the other version.

I have tried to attack this problem from several angles, but nothing has been successful.  Is this even possible?  Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me.

1. First I used the RegistrySearch Element to store the path into a Proprty Element.
2. Secondly I created a new Component Element with same GUID in both versions.  In this componenent I created a new RegistryValue and used this as the key path.  Then added CopyFile Elements for each shared DLL.
3. Added a ComponentRef Element into a Feature Element.

Here is the code for Part 1:

```
<Property Id="ANOTHERPRODUCTSPATH">
  <RegistrySearch Id="ANOTHERPRODUCTSPATH" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\XXXX\XXXX\XXXXX" Name="[whateverItIs]" Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

Here is the code for Part 2:

```
<Component Id="CommonDLLs" Guid="[Your-GUID]" Directory="Doesn'tMatterButRequiredForSomeReason">
  <RegistryValue Id="yourid" Root="YourRoot" Key="YourNewKey" Name="Installed" Value="1" Type="integer" KeyPath="yes" />
  <CopyFile Id="Shared1.dll" FileId="Shared1.dll" DestinationProperty="ANOTHERPRODUCTSPATH" DestinationName="Shared1.dll"/>
  <CopyFile Id="Shared2.dll" FileId="Shared2.dll" DestinationProperty="ANOTHERPRODUCTSPATH" DestinationName="Shared2.dll"/>
  ...//the rest of your shared dlls
</Component>
```

And for Part 3:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="$(var.ProductNameLong)" Level="1"
         ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION" TypicalDefault="install" >

  ...//existing componentrefs
  <ComponentRef Id="CommonDLLs" />


</Feature>
```